# strategy to handle state with several asynchronous events in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I was wondering how I can manage a state, which gets accessed by several asynchronous events, like click handler, timeouts, etc.

If I understand it right, then in the code below, there is the risk that if the timeout gets triggered **at the same time** then my clickHandler, there will be **data loss.**

How can I manage a the state without the risk of data loss.

```
const TestComp = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setMessages([...messages, "new"]);
  };

  setInterval(() => {
    setMessages([...messages, "new async"]);
  }, 3000);


  return <button onClick={clickHandler}>click me</button>;
};
```

I am asking because this is a simple demo. In a real world example I want to build a chat app, that has multiple websockets (async) events which are storing data into the state.

Comment: What data loss is possible here? JS is single threaded, so the ordering is nondeterministic but both strings will be added to `messages`. `messages.push("cde");` is not how React works, though, you'll need to remove that regardless of async or otherwise because mutating state is off-limits--you have to call `setState` if you want to change state and trigger a re-render correctly.

Comment: @ggorlen you are right, I made a mistakes. I removed the .push.. but my question is still there. I need websockets, that are handling an event to any time and accessing state data. interval is just a simple example

Comment: It's still a broken component--if the interval isn't cleared if the component is unmounted, you're trying to `setState` on a dead component. It's OK to have a handler and an async socket callback that could fire at any time modifying the same state. Have you been running into corruption with this setup, assuming it's corrected otherwise? The updater function as proposed in the answer is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

In order to maintain your state without race conditions, you can pass `setMessages` an updater **function**, rather than the new **value**:

```
const updateMessages = (prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, "new async"];
setMessages(updateMessages);
```

This will guarantee that the update will be performed on the most updated state, rather than the value of `messages` in the specific time of `setMessages` call.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly: so data don't gets lost, because it will internally wait until the state can be accessed to store the data?

Comment: It doesn't wait, but just updates the state using its *current* value. What happens when you `setState` with a value is that it uses the value in a certain point in time, which might differ while the update process is taking place